# JVM remote profiling with JVisualVM

Tags: java, jvm, profiling, jvisualvm

I am trying to profile my jvm applications on a remote host. 
I am using Jvisualvm
I setup jstatd as recomended in this (link removed, leads to phishing website). 
I am able to "telnet remotehost 1099" successfully. All the tcp/ip ports are firewall open on the remote.

I added my remote host in jvisualvm. Also, made sure the jstatd port is the 1099 with a refresh of 3 secs.

I started my application with

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8011 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

But, my jvm applications dont show up in my jvisualvm. Is there anything else I need to configure or check ?

jvisualvm 1.3.5
local: Mac OSX Oracle jdk 1.6.37
remote: centos 6 oracle jdk 1.6.24

Answer (score 1):

1) You should start your application with `JMX` enabled
Example for remote connection

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote    
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9990   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false   
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

2) You should have `JMX` classes to be able to do something with them. I suppose you are aware of this

Comment: yes, i updated my question with the command line options i am using. The part I am not sure about the communication links. a) Jvisualvm talks to the jstatd default port 1099. What is the relationship to the jxmremote.port. b) Also, not sure how what you mean by have JXM classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start `jstatd` on the remote machine. For this purpose create a `jstatd.all.policy` file in the home directory of your remote machine and add the following lines:

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {   
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Then on the command line of your remote machine you will type

```
jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname={Your IP address} '
```

Once `jstatd` service start on the remote machine you basically add the remote connection IP address connection on the jvisualVM UI using *add remote host*.

The Oracle documents for JvisualVM can be referred at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_remote.html but it is really confusing to understand `jstatd` steps.

Comment: An additional note is to make sure you start _VisualVM_ as a regular user i.e. do **NOT** use `psexec -s`.  The feature in VisualVM is also called _Add jstatd Connection_ in the right-click menu on _Local_.